# Find index of all duplicate elements in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

It's hard to explain why I need index of duplicate elements in array. When I tried to fetch the index of element in traditional way it shows only one index, but I need to fetch the all index of duplicate values
for ex:

```
NSArray *array=@[@"one",@"one",@"one",@"two",@"two",@"four",@"four",@"four"];
int index = [array indexOfObject:element];
NSLog(@"index %d",index);
```

here if I try to fetch index of " `one` " it shows index is **0** but I need to get further indexes of `one`

Comment: u want all index as array of matched index or individual indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the index of duplicates like this:

```
NSArray *array=@[@"one",@"one",@"one",@"two",@"two",@"four",@"four",@"four"];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
 {
     if ([obj isEqualToString:@"one"])
     {
         NSLog(@"index %d",idx);

     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int i,count=0;
for (i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
    if element == [array objectAtIndex:i] {
        indices[count++] = i;
    }
}
```

Declare an empty array indices, and indices will contain all the indices of the given element.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *element = @"one";
NSArray *array=@[@"one",@"one",@"one",@"two",@"two",@"four",@"four",@"four"];

NSIndexSet *matchingIndexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj isEqual:element];
}];

[matchingIndexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)idx);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I don't think the NSArray methods are going to help you here, so you're going to have to write some pretty basic code. There is probably a cleaner answer, but here is a fairly simply solution to the problem.

This just goes through the array, and creates an NSDictionary for each unique number.  It assumes the array is sorted as your example was, so simply checks the prior index's value against the current index to see if they have changed.  When they change, it knows it's done with that value and saves the dictionary to an array.

```
NSArray *array=@[@"one",@"one",@"one",@"two",@"two",@"four",@"four",@"four"];
NSString *priorString = array[0];
NSMutableDictionary *duplicatesByKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *indexesOfDuplicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int index = 0;
for (NSString *string in array) {
    if ([priorString isEqualToString:string]) {
        [indexesOfDuplicates addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]];
    } else {
        [duplicatesByKey setObject:indexesOfDuplicates forKey:priorString];
        indexesOfDuplicates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [indexesOfDuplicates addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:index]];
    }
    priorString = string;
    index ++;
}
[duplicatesByKey setObject:indexesOfDuplicates forKey:priorString];
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NSCountedSet * countedSet = [NSCountedSet setWithArray: array];
```

and

```
NSSet * uncountedSet = [NSSet setWithArray: array];
```

-- to create a counted set from your array, and a conventional NSSet.

Then:

```
[countedSet minusSet: uncountedSet];
```

countedSet will now contain only elements for the duplicates (if any), and the countForObject: method will return the number of duplicates (in excess of 1) for that element.